# Integration testing with Firebase-Server

Tags: firebase-authentication

How can I create a "User-Token" on the Server side for testing???

What I want is something like this: (pseudo code)

```java
@Test
public void testIdentifyByToken() throws Exception {
    CountDownLatch signal = new CountDownLatch(1);

    // @Before
    // auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword("urbi@orbi.it", "12345678").addOnCompleteListener( ... )
    //
    token = "";
    final FirebaseUser currentUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
    currentUser.getToken(false).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull final Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
            assertTrue(task.isSuccessful());

            token = task.getResult().getToken();

            signal.countDown();
        }
    });
    signal.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    assertTrue(token.length() == 9999);

    signal = new CountDownLatch(1);
    userid = "";
    final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    auth.verifyIdToken(token).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<FirebaseToken>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull final Task<FirebaseToken> task) {
            //assertTrue(task.isSuccessful());

            userid = task.getResult().getUid();
            signal.countDown();
        }
    });

    signal.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    assertTrue(0 == signal.getCount());

    assertEquals("xxxxxxxxxxx", userid);
}
```

How else can I test different roles e.g. on the server side????